# Flutter silent push notifications - does such thing exists?

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

I want to trigger some code of my app on a daily basis.

Is there something similar to silent push notifications on Flutter, that will trigger part of the code, event when app is closed?

I already reviewed package `flutter_local_notifications` but there is not anything like `silent` or `invokeScheduled`.

Comment: You have to use native code to apply this feature

Answer (score -1):

To schedule background task at regular basis use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager).

```
Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
  "periodic-task-identifier", 
  "simplePeriodicTask", 
  frequency: Duration(hours: 24),
)
```

Comment: is there way to schedule it at midnight? as the above will run 24 from current time of the day, wouldn't it?